# Dependecies not met --  language-selector

Tags: updates, dpkg, dependencies, language-support

```
uri@uri-MS-7267:~$ LANG=c sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for uri: 
Setting up language-selector-common (0.6.7) ...
dpkg: error processing language-selector-common (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector:
language-selector depends on language-selector-common (= 0.6.7); however:
Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing language-selector (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
language-selector-common
language-selector
```

Why am I getting this?  Happened after I updated today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is/was a bug in the postinst script in that package.  I'm sure the developers will fix that ASAP (if they didn't do so already).

This is the relevant bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/+bug/766534

You can recognize this type of bugs from a line like the following:

```
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

This means something went wrong in the script that handles whatever tasks need to happen after a package is installed or upgraded (e.g. restart a service after it was upgraded, etc.).

Comment: I just updated again, it's fixed now.

Comment: @Uri: I added the bug report in case you want more details...  ;)